# Transfering files from my HTC to my laptop fails via Bluetooth, Why?

Tags: files, android, bluetooth, devices, transfer

I am trying to send some files from my HTC to my laptop having ubuntu 12.04 through a bluetooth; but while trying to send files i see the following error on my htc device:-

> This transfer is forbidden by the target device

What does this error means, any permission issues? or something else. What settings do I need to make so that ubuntu can accept files easily.

I am able to send files from ubuntu to htc device via Bluetooth.

Comment: Please don't change your question midway. An [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/174817/88802) about regular MTP file transfer came in [before](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/174811/2) you've [edited](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/174811/4) your question to change it to a Bluetooth question.

Answer (score 5):

This might be happening because by default ubuntu doesn't recieve files over bluetooth. One  possible solution might be to enable recieving files over bluetooth. Open the personal file sharing preferences window.[image: dash]
Then you'll see this window.
Just check the 'Recieve files in Downloads folder over bluetooth' and you're good to go.

[image: personal file sharing pref]

### For Ubuntu 18.04 and later:

File sharing can be changed in Settings -> Sharing,
which is turned OFF by default.

Also you might need to reconnect after changing this.

[image: Sharing Preferences]

Comment: How do I do this from Unity in Ubuntu 18? The option seems to have moved to gnome only. Perhaps I'm missing a package

Answer (score 0):

On the HTC device, go to `Settings` -> `Connect to PC` and look at `Default connection type`. If this is set to 'Charge only', you can either select 'Disk drive', or check the 'Ask me' box.

This should allow you to mount the drives on the HTC device.

Comment: The question is about bluetooth file transfer, not direct USB connection.

Comment: @JavierRivera This was answered before the question was edited to "Bluetooth"! See [revision 2](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/174811/2) for example. This was certainly not clear at the time this answer came in.

Answer (score 0):

gnome-bluetooth (3.2.2-0ubuntu5) now has a working bi-directory I think. I used blueman before, I also had this bug occur on my HTC G4 G7 G11. bug can be found at https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/872044, etc.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to add where you got your information from as citing an up to date source of information is quite recommended for such answers.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a workaround:

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
sudo mkdir /media/onex
sudo chmod 775 /media/onex
sudo mtpfs -o allow_other /media/onex
gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

and add the following line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
```

and then:

```
sudo service udev restart
```

Didnt work for me but has for others.

Comment: The question is about bluetooth transfer, mtp is not relevant here.